# SVG Sprites - What if element is taller and wider than image?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-sprites

I want to put all SVG graphics used on a page in a sprite sheet to lower HTTP requests. Most of the sprites are actually really tiny so I have used `background-size` a lot.
In some cases, the background image intentionally does not fill out the assigned element completely. Is it still possible to use a sprite sheet without "leaking" of other graphics on the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included "repeat: no-repeat" in your css?

If this isn't fixing the problem try spreading your images out further in your image sprite.